# Is it possible to LIKE a Facebook Page via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is it possible to LIKE a Facebook Page via the Open Graph API?

Maybe POST to "http://graph.facebook.com/#{FB_PAGE_ID}/likes ???

This is the only thing I could find in the API about creating a LIKE:

/POST_ID/likes  like the given post     none

Comment: I also want to implement "page like" feature while logging through the facebook graph API. Is it possible ? Does anyone has worked on it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's not possible. You can not like pages. Check this: ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api) . I had to use a website to do like a page.

The error I always got was something about permission whitelist. It seems that this specific function is only available for specific apps.

At the top of my head, I think you can get a edge create notification with the javascrip sdk that you can use as callback for adding a fb page

Comment: Is there a way to get a callback after someone has "LIKED" a page (through iframe or fbml).

Comment: I added that to the answer, but i'm not 100% certain

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. You need to retrieve the unique identifier of the page/photo/post/etc. you wish to like, then make a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<IDENTIFIER>/likes`.

Check out [this page of the Facebook Developers documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), under the subheading "Publishing".