# How to like a Person using Facebook Social Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

let us start with the known bug from facebook's own dev site:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=74700

> It appears this is a problem with the IDs of objects other than Posts.  Posts
>   have object IDs of the form USERID_POSTID.  When used with the /likes/ URL,
>   Posts can apparently be liked because their URL conforms to this format. 
>   However, other items, such as status messages, photos, videos, etc. all conform
>   to the simpler ITEMID object ID.  If you add the person who posted the item
>   (from the from field) to make it of the form USERID_ITEMID, you can also like
>   and unlike these other types of items.

So let us take http://www.facebook.com/CirqueduSoleil as an example, it has a person ID of 144074117500. For some wierd reason, it is a Person. So, how can I like a Person with the Social graph API.... I am definitely running into the "Whitelist Error" when I try to /144074117500/likes

So how can I "like" anything besides something in the format of userid_postid, in other very simple word: how can I simply like a person using the social graph api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are not talking about "persons" (users) but [facebook pages](http://www.facebook.com/FacebookPages). And secondly, facebook developers can not create a application that allows to like facebook pages. You can like statuses, comments, pictures, videos, shared links via API (doing POST request on //likes), but not facebook pages. Users can like pages only with the facebook [social plugins fb:like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) (or using the facebook website).

So, why whitelists ? I guess because Facebook can allow some privileged partners to add this feature, but that is not widely open.

You can check some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379092/is-it-possible-to-like-a-facebook-page-via-the-api) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api) answers for this questions.

Comment: More things I'm dissapointed about facebook is the Android 'SDK' which is facebook putting a wrapper around some javascript, rendering slow ass webpages on the mobile and calling it an Android API. The "WEB" is past its peak. I've been devoting 100% of my time to Android for almost 2 years now, and its definitely paying off. I've been to India, where some people in big cities live in mud huts if they're lucky, yet for some reason they still spring for mobiles. There is no doubt in my mind that the mobile market is the most interesting, and growth oriented market.

Comment: I tend to believe your answer based on testing and other posts I have seen, but would prefer not to.... as I'd like my Android app to allow a user to "Like" it's Facebook app equivalent via a UI button....  do I have to embedd a WebView of some web page with the social plugin in it to do this?