# Press Facebook like button from code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-like

is there a way to directly click like on a fan page in facebook from iphone / ipad application without use the fb library ?
Or to open it in a UIWebView but directly on like?

thanks a lot.

A

Comment: Yikes. If that can be done, I can't imagine the spamming that would occur.

Comment: why, what kind of spamming would that incur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not even possible with the fb library. You can only embedded a uiwebview with the like button itself, directly from facebook, generated here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like
Be carfeul however, if the user is not logged into FB, you'll have to show him a full WebView to be able to log in.

It's very well possible to like posts and other thinks using the graph API tho. Just not pages, facebook restricts that for some reason.

{edit}: [Is it possible to LIKE a Facebook Page via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379092/is-it-possible-to-like-a-facebook-page-via-the-api/4379468#4379468) another example of this

Comment: ok, i will use fb library. It's easy and resolve all of my problems. thanks.

Comment: no it won't :) You can't Like a page using any facebook library! The user has to actually click on something to do this!