# C# code to like a Page on facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to LIKE a Facebook Page via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379092/is-it-possible-to-like-a-facebook-page-via-the-api)

How can I make a user who has granted facebook permission for my application to programmability make him like a specific facebook page on his behalf ? C# MVC code

Answer (score 1):

This question gets asked weekly here and is a duplicate of a lot of questions, such as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379092/is-it-possible-to-like-a-facebook-page-via-the-api)  You cannot force a user to like a page through any code in any language on any platform.  The only way a user can like your page is 1) going to your facebook page and clicking "Like", or 2) clicking on a "Like" button that you embed via an iframe or xfbml code  on your page, as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Technically option 3) is to prompt the user for their username and password and scrape the facebook site by posting with the users credentials to facebooks like url.  This is a fast way to get your app/page kicked off of facebook though as it violates their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not offer write permission to like something on a user's behalf.  Currently you can ask for write permissions to: post to a user's wall, create an event, RSVP for an event, send the user SMS messages, perform a checkin and create/edit friend lists.