# implement facebook page like functionality in windows phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there any sample code for implementing the functionality of liking a page in facebook from windows phone app?

I have tried publishing the posts to facebook in my app.But want to know if I have to handle this scenario differently .

Comment: gone through the link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129351/c-sharp-code-to-like-a-page-on-facebook . Looks like we can't do it from the api..