# How to do like page on facebook in program side

Tags: facebook

I have problem on Facebook "like" button.
I put facebook "like" button in my page but I click that button it is not navigate to what I gave in href link and I want to perform facebook "like" button action same as facebook.
I can "like" [this link](https://graph.facebook.com/carnival) on facebook how to do same as in my website using facebook "like" button ?

Comment: the question is not clear. could you please take some time to frame the question? help us to help you :)

Comment: This user looks like a spammer or a bot. He/she/it aksed same question about facebook "like" button 6 times already.

Comment: Stop asking this questionl; I've merged 6 of them. You have 5 answers saying the same thing. Stop. Now.

Answer (score 2):

You can only 'Like' a fan Page by clicking the FB supplied button that sits in the parent FB page outside of your iframed application page. As frustrating as this can be to designers and UX developers it is potential security flaw if an application (boxed in as a Fan page) is allowed to 'Like' itself. I.e. users could be duped into 'Liking' a Page onload without their consent.

You can get the count of Likes for a Fan page. That is the only 'Like' action permitted on this object type.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=294757

Answer (score 1):

You can't add likes to a profile using the Facebook Api. 
Read here for more details ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can only like a post via the graph api acccording to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible via any of the API's to like a page programmatically.

This is to prevent spam where people create apps to mass-like pages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a user like a page. That isn't possible unless you use a XSS attack (which facebook probably prevents), and you'll get banned from facebook. If you want to know how to place a like button, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/