# Facebook async with no facebook buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I made a Facebook async implementation where you can like different items of the page.

You can see my implementation in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aWVA/1/).

Code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement("script"); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js";
    document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
} ());
```

Now I have three Facebook like buttons. But my problem is, I want it so that you can click on the `a href` links. When you click on the first like this `<a>` element. Than you like the first message / bericht.

How can I make that?

Comment: Your post doesn't really make sense.  You want it so that instead of clicking the "Like" buttons, for your users to be able to click the links instead?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Instead of like buttons. I want you can click on the links. When you click on the links. Then the same happens when you click on the button like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to like a post (On Facebook) using the provided Graph API and FQL, not a page on the Open Graph.

I'm afraid that you have to use the implementations that Facebook provide.

Please see this post: ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: This is probably done for two reasons: (a) maintaining control over branding; (b) maintaining a consistent styling for the Like button to avoid user confusion/opportunity for scamming. I'm pretty happy with that, tbh.

Comment: Security reasons as well: if apps had control to make a user like their page, it could be abused.