# Method to like a page via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Like' a page using facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Can we able to like a page via facebbok API. I found method to like a post throught API, but I found nothing in the documentation.

Comment: The same question in [this topic] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Just go to this site [vist] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and take down the code that you need.

Comment: Thank for your reply. This page help me to get a HTML code to put into my Website. But i would like to do that with API facebook  : https://graph.facebook.com/${PAGE_ID}/likes?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN} i try this but it give an error.