# How to create url_like by using graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How do I create url_like using graph api?

This URL shows like count that (http://example.com)
https://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com

```
{
   "id": "http://example.com",
   "shares": 131086
}
```

but instead of retrieving the count, I'd like to create a like using the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: How is your question different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is [described here in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/).
The short version is:

```
url -F 'access_token=...' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/313449204401/likes
```

Note: To create rather than retrieve the likes, the request needs to be an HTTP `POST` rather than `GET` since this service has a [RESTful architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services).