# iOS Phonegap Like Button (phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect)

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-like

i have a problem with implementing a "Like-Button" in a Phonegap Application for iOS.

I'm using the phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect plugin and it works.(I can post things on my wall and so on)

But i can't realize a "Like-Button" of a specific page.(There is just a white space where the button should be)

I searched for hours on Google, but there were nothing which really helped me.

My current code is:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/oxfam.de" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What kind of object are you attempting to like?

Comment: I want to like a Facebook page of an oragnisation. In this case: http://www.facebook.com/oxfam.de

Comment: Posting the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point in time you cannot like facebook pages via the graph. Basically Facebook has give the ability to like out site objects via the graph but internal pages are still off limits - due to the potential of spammers.

[Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/likes/)

[Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Eventually this will be possible I think, but for now it is not.