# Like with OpenGraph protocol

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I can publish without problems with the facebook api OpenGraph, but I do not see how to automatically "like" a page with OpenGraph, in fact I would like the user to like automatically a page when he accepts my application, an idea on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a user like a page on Facebook programmatically with the API... Wise choice of Facebook's too, imagine the abuse that would occur. You should use the facebook like button instead.

Confirmations:

['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)