# Like a FB page without using the mouse?

Tags: facebook-like

Hi all this is my fist Q here

i want to make a keyboard shortcut or a command that i can run from the java script console or any way to do a Facebook page like (the page is in the Facebook not on my site)

so i'am on a FB page and i want to like it without using mouse and clicking like i want to make it with the keyboard or maybe a java command or any thing but using the mouse
or maybe make a script that auto like a FB page when i visit ?
is this possible ?

any ideas ?

Comment: ctrl+L if i remember correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

You try this shortcut key from Keyboard
Press Alt+8 and Like Page

Comment: when i press ALT+8 nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Which Browser you use?
Now you see this and implement.

Windows

Firefox: Shift + Alt + 8
Chrome: Alt + 8

Comment: Alt + 8 i tried it on windows on chrome browser it toked me to the FB page

Comment: i am check this shortcut key on  FB page than after answer send to you.