# Is it possible to like a page on facebook without using the social plugin - like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a UI project which makes use of a SVG browser Ekioh. Part of the requirement is to allow a user to LIKE a facebook page through the application. But since Ekioh isn't compatible with the FB javascript SDK, I can't seem to use the social plugin - like button. I looked into possibilities of using the graph API to implement this but it turned out this isn't possible by design. One can use graph API to like other objects but not page!

So in order to make it happen, I'm wondering what my options are if there is any, even if they were workarounds? Could some gurus out there kindly point me to the right direction please?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the iframe interface?

```html
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: No I haven't. If I could use html then I'd go for the URL or iframe code. But it's a SVG application. Facebook javascript SDK isn't working in Ekioh for a start although FB claims their login works on everything (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/), but it's not true. It didn't work in Ekioh running on a linux box.