# How to like on URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

i want to let my users like my facebook fanpage on url.

Something like;

```
<?php
$fb = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId=45454854467898645';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $fb; ?>">Click for linking FAN page </a>
```

How do i make it like when `"Click for linking FAN page"` is clicked

Comment: You can't. because of cross domain, why not just use `iframe` provided by facebook? otherwise you have to authenticate the user and use their `access_token` to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Like' a page using Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api)