# How to Creat PHP script to like Page using Access token's?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Hello every body i am trying to Creat A simple PHP script in order to like facebook page using access Tokens .

i have alot of Access Tokens in database that called getaccess 
i already try to creat a php code that is integratted with Js Ajax script  and api graph from facebook as showen down but it does not work.

so i try to use this php code but i does not work

```
<script>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT id, title, content FROM posts';

mysql_select_db('getaccess');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{
       echo "
    function HaveFun()
        {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token={$row[2]}&method=POST&url=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-page,
      success: success
    });


     ";
    }
    mysql_free_result($retval);

    mysql_close($conn);


    ?>

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="HaveFun();Page()">
```

Comment: Which part? I can see that your $retreval can get error, is it that part?

Comment: I used this method to show Ajax code that is duplicated but with different access

Comment: is there any onther code  to excute this line https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token={$row[2]}&method=POST&url=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-page  with different access token

Comment: You can't like pages using the graph api you can only like pages with the like button or directly in facebook check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061054/like-a-page-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help to Creat PHP Script to Like Page Using Access from DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438147/need-help-to-creat-php-script-to-like-page-using-access-from-db)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot like Pages through the Graph API. Facebook doesn't offer this functionality, and it's for a good reason. You only can use the official like buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can like facebook pages through graph call. Like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<--page_id-->/likes?method=post&access_token=<--here goes the access token-->

Note: Access token must be from an app that has permission to like pages on your behalf like "Sony Xperia app"

Comment: _“Actually you can like facebook pages through graph call.”_ – no, you can not.